# Does Tcl have an equivalent of PERL and Ruby backtic

Tags: ruby, perl, tcl, backticks

In Ruby/PERL, I can very easily get the console output of a system command fed into a file. For example:

```
$k = `ls`
```

Would input the output of ls into variable $k in PERL (and Ruby).
How can one do something like this in Tcl?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `exec` command to get the same.

```
set output [ exec ls ]
puts $output
```

Man page : [exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm)

Comment: May I add for completeness that while this is indeed the general solution for capturing the output from a system command, in the specific case of getting a list of file names, the `glob` command is more useful and portable.